# Ctools: stay always within modal window

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

When I load some pages using Ctools modal window, those pages have many another links, submit buttons etc, so when I follow those links, I loose the window. Drupal Overlay has no problems with it.

Is it possible to emulate Drupal Overlay using Ctools?

Answer (score 1):

You may can use this module
[Overlay Paths](http://drupal.org/project/overlay_paths)

This is a simple module that enables administrators to use the built-in Overlay for non-admin pages.

This means that you can use the overlay for doing popups without adding yet more javascript libraries to your site.

This module is designed to be used by module developers comfortable with writing code to define which pages should appear in the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/ajax-not-output-to-ctools-modal-when-using-pager), and I discovered that the problem was that the other links did not have the **ctools-use-modal** class assigned to them. I got around this by writing a custom jQuery behavior that assigned that class to the appropriate links, in my case to the links in a pager:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.addCtoolsModalClass = {
    attach: function (context) {
      if (context = '#modalContent') {
        $('#modalContent .pagination li a').addClass('ctools-use-modal');
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

This will cause your clicked links to stay within your modal.