# Ajax not output to Ctools modal when using pager

Tags: 7, ajax, paging, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

So in my [continuing quest](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/using-ajax-with-pager-in-ctools-modal-window) to display a form with Solr search results in a Ctools modal window and use a pager, I've managed to get everything to display fine after the initial search, but when I use the pager, I get a white screen with the data in json format instead of everything displayed in the modal again. Here is the relevant code:

```
function imgsearch_page($ajax, $id, $a, $b) {
  if ($ajax) {
    //Load the modal library and add the modal javascript.
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');

    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
      'title' => t('Image Search Form'),
      'next_field_id' => $id,
    );

    // Use ctools to generate ajax instructions for the browser to create
    // a form in a modal popup.
    $search_form = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('imgsearch_form', $form_state);

    if (($form_state['executed'] && $form_state['ajax']) || isset($_GET['page'])) {
      // If the form has been submitted, there may be additional instructions
      // such as dismissing the modal popup.
      if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
        $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
      }

      if ($form_state['values']['search_terms'] != '' || isset($_GET['search_terms'])) {
        $page_num = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

        if ($_GET['search_terms']) {
          $form_state['values']['search_terms'] = $_GET['search_terms'];
        }
        $results = nb_image_search_search($form_state['values'], $page_num);

        if (is_array($results['images']) && count($results['images'] > 0)) {
          $next_field_id = $form_state['next_field_id'];
          // Create object to store file and target field info. To be stored in ctools cache.
          $file_info = new stdClass();
          // Generate the field name.  field_images is a multivalue field collection, so we just need the next available option
          // in the $field_images['und'] array. The second number (for field_image) will always be 0 since it
          // is a single value field.
          $file_info->fieldname['url'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-image-und-0-imgsearch-file-url';
          $file_info->fieldname['person'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-person-und-0-value';
          $file_info->fieldname['organization'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-organization-und-0-value';
          $file_info->fieldname['year'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-year-und-0-value';

          $file_info->fids = array();

          // Theme the results as a table.
          $header = array(t('Image'), t('File Name'), t('Add to field'));
          $rows = array();
          foreach ($results['images'] as $image) {
            // Create image style derivative for each image.
            $imagestyle = array(
              'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
              'path' => $image['filepath'] . $image['filename'],
              'width' => '',
              'height' => '',
              'alt' => '',
              'title' => $image['filename'],
            );
            $styled_image = theme('image_style', $imagestyle);
            $fid = $image['fid'];

            $rows[] = array(
              'image' => $styled_image,
              'name' => $image['filename'],
              'add' => ctools_ajax_text_button("select", "imgsearch/nojs/imgadd/" . $fid . '/' . $next_field_id, t('Select')),
            );

            $file_info->fids[$fid] = $image['filename'];

            // Cache values for Person, Organization, and Year if they exist.
            foreach (array('person', 'organization', 'year') as $field) {
              if (isset($image[$field])) {
                $file_info->meta[$fid][$field] = $image[$field];
              }
            }
          }
          //Cache image name in ctools object cache so it can be used later in nb_image_search_image_add()
          ctools_include('object-cache');
          ctools_object_cache_set('imgsearch', 'imgsearch_' . $next_field_id, $file_info);

          // Create a render array ($build) which will be themed as a table with a
          // pager.
          $build['search_form'] = isset($search_form[0]) ? drupal_build_form('imgsearch_form', $form_state) : $search_form;
          $build['imgsearch_table'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'table',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#rows' => $rows,
            '#empty' => t('There were no matching results found'),
          );

          // Attach the pager theme.
          $pager = pager_default_initialize($results['total_found'], $results['rows']);
          $build['imgsearch_pager'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'pager',
            '#parameters' => array(
              'search_terms' => $form_state['values']['search_terms'],
              //TODO: add params for Person, Organization, and Year.
              ),
          );

          $form_state['values']['title'] = t('Search Results');
          $output = ctools_modal_form_render($form_state['values'], $build);

          print ajax_render($output);
          drupal_exit();
        }
        else {
          $build['no_results'] = array(
            'markup' => '<div class="no-results>No images found</div>',
          );
        }
      }
    }
    elseif (!isset($output)) {
      $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('imgsearch_form', $form_state);
      // Return the ajax instructions to the browser via ajax_render().
      print ajax_render($output);
      drupal_exit();
    }
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('imgsearch_form', $id);
  }
}
```

The only real difference is that since form field values are removed somehow when the form is submitted via ajax, I use the #parameters element in the pager array, which puts it in $_GET[], allowing me to access it in the search function (nb_image_search_search()). The page argument is also there, put there by the pager. Since ctools_modal_form_wrapper() returns the form in rendered mode, I have to rebuild it again to pass it to ctools_modal_form_render().

Other than that, I don't see any differences. I've stepped through the code all the way to the call to drupal_json_encode() in ajax_render(), but can't get any farther than that.

What would be causing the json to just be displayed on a white screen instead of displaying in the modal, but only when I'm using the pager link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a missing class in my pager links. Whenever you use CTools Modal, you have to add the ctools-use-modal class to the link. My first thought was to add the class as a link attribute in the link themeing functions, since the [theme_pager_link()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/pager.inc?h=7.x#n594) function accepts attributes (via $values['attributes']). However, the functions that actually call theme_pager_link() (e.g. [theme_pager_previous()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/pager.inc?h=7.x#n480), [theme_pager_next()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/pager.inc?h=7.x#n519), and [theme_pager_last()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/pager.inc?h=7.x#n556)) don't bother to actually pass attributes, so there's no way to get them to the link function. Sigh.

So, to work around this, I just created a quick jQuery behavior that adds the ctools-use-modal class to the pager links:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.addCtoolsModalClass = {
        attach: function (context) {
          $('#modalContent .pagination ul li a').addClass('ctools-use-modal');
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

and voila!, it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

use [array_chunks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) after [pager_default_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7).

A small example from my code, hope it will help you.

```
$per_page = 10;
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($result['node_ids']), $per_page);
$chunks = array_chunk(node_load_multiple($result['node_ids']),$per_page, TRUE);
```